# are there any websites where I can just download images for menus, icons, graphics for web pages etc, w/o having to reference the author

Tags: css, image, graphics, icons

Basically with all the free website images, menu and button icons we have to reference the original source in our web page.  Any website that offers them and we can use them freely w/o having to reference anything or anyone?

Comment: google web graphics+free

Comment: He clearly already has; that search does not limit results by license terms

Comment: well i find lots pretty quickly doing the above.

Comment: this is clearly a webmasters.stackexchange.com question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open Clipart Library](http://www.openclipart.org/) provides a variety of images under a public domain license.

Answer (score 0):

try icon search engine on google and check them all out - you can filter based on royalty

also you can  search for royalty free icons or best free icons on google

also try gettyimage.com,corbis.com etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.iconfinder.com/